# how to write cdktf module instead terraform module

Tags: terraform, cdktf

Instead of referring terraform module in cdktf i want to refer CDKTF typescript files to combine several resources as one. How can i achieve this?

Below is for terraform module but expecting something like this for cdktf

```
"terraformModules": [   
{
"name": "my-local-module",
"source": "./New folder"
}
],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import {myExport} from "./path-to-ts-file";` and `export myExport = ...` in the file you are exporting from. You can see an example for this in the serverless typescript demo: https://github.com/hashicorp/cdktf-integration-serverless-example/blob/main/main.ts#L5 & https://github.com/hashicorp/cdktf-integration-serverless-example/blob/main/posts/index.ts#L13

Comment: can i write something like this for my existing cdktf scripts to convert into modules ....    module "rg" {
  source                  = "./Modules/01_Azure_ResGrp"
  Resource_Group_Name     = var.Resource_Group_Name
  Resource_Group_Location = var.Resource_Group_Location
}

Comment: If you want to make your cdktf code available I'd encourage you to check out my talk on CDK day around this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8tO-ymVQPg&t=10260s

Comment: TL;DR: https://github.com/DanielMSchmidt/cdktf-tf-module-stack is a good way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Terraform module, then run `cdktf get` and finally import it, e.g.:

```
import { MyLocalModule } from "./.gen/modules/my-local-module";
```

Comment: This is only for terraform module but i have cdktf scripts and i want to create module for that something like      
module "rg" {
  source                  = "./Modules/01_Azure_ResGrp"
  Purpose                 = var.Purpose
  Project_Name            = var.Project_Name
  Environment             = var.Environment
  Resource_Group_Name     = var.Resource_Group_Name
  Resource_Group_Location = var.Resource_Group_Location
}

Comment: Yes, once you import you're module into TS, you can create a class that extends TerraformStack, for example: `class MyLocalModule extends TerraformStack`, that's where you will start setting the variables and everything as a regular module.

Comment: An example for the import statement in Python would be `from imports.terraform_google_modules.google import ProjectFactory`